# WaterMark on the print out html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/dhaileytaha/g92gr1sy/3/

the above fiddle has a print out page. I need a WaterMark on that print out page.
i dont know how can we do it. wether js or jquery or css or none of the above
Please help

```
 document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
 var password;

 var pass1 = "cool";

 password = prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!', ' ');

 if (password == pass1) {
   printElement(document.getElementById("example"));
   //console.log(elem);
  }
 }
   //console.log(elem);
   function printElement(elem) {
     var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
     console.log(elem);
     var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

   if (!$printSection) {
     $printSection = document.createElement("div");
     $printSection.id = "printSection";
     document.body.appendChild($printSection);
   }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
   }
```

Comment: The easiest fix, I think, is adding the watermark to your HTML. 
Hide it by default within `@media screen {}` and display it between `@media print {}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **"media query: Print"** might help you out here. It is basically the same as all other media queries (like "screen" and "projection" etc)

You can build an element (Watermark) and show it only in print mode:

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

You can reffer to [this detailed explanation](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/)

Answer (score 0):

if the server can provide a watermark image, and all of your users are using webkit browser, try

```
@media print {
 * {
       -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}

container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(picture-link)'
```

if not, try this

```
container.style.position = 'relative'

  // watermarkElm is a dom node
  if (watermarkElm) {
    const background = document.createElement('section')

    const baseStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      height: '120%',
      width: '120%',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      wordWrap: 'break-word',
      wordBreak: 'normal',
      zIndex: 9999,
      pointerEvents: 'none'
    }

    Object.assign(background.style, baseStyle)
    container.appendChild(background)

    // watermarkCount 
    renderWatermark(watermarkElm.outerHTML, watermarkCount, background)

function renderWatermark (tpl, watermarkCount, background) {
  if (!tpl) {
    throw new Error('invalid watermark template')
  }

  background.innerHTML = new Array(watermarkCount).fill(tpl).join('')
  return background
}
```