# How to add watermark when using window.print()?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code that uses window.print() to print the screen. I need to add watermark to while printing. Is there any way to achieve this ? Please let me know if anyone knows

Comment: Add the watermark image and give it `display: block` inside `@media print`

Comment: Use CSS to overlay it over all elements?

Comment: If you want to use it to protect some assets(Online products as images that you want to sale) use server side, otherwise anyone can hack the browser and steal your image/pdf/etc.

Comment: Here is my answer about print watermark in another question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43652651/6370454

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer about print watermark in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652651/6370454 – HermanLin

If your server can provide you a watermark picture and all your users are using webkit browsers, see the easier way. If not, use javascript to add the watermark before print