# add watermark while printing from html to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to add watermark while printing from HTML to pdf in every page in this below-mentioned code:

```
$scope.printTableFunc = function (divName) {      
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;  
    console.log(printContents)         
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank','width=1080,height=960');  
    popupWin.document.open();     
    popupWin.document.write(`
       <html>
         <head >
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../res/css/style.css" />
         </head>
         <body onload="window.print()">${printContents}
         </body>
       </html>
    `);    
    popupWin.document.close();     
}
```

Comment: Please try researching before posting, this may solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469871/watermark-on-the-print-out-html-page/43652651#43652651

Comment: where you adding watermark css